# How to align multiple equations in Marp (a tool to convert .md files into PDF)?

Tags: latex, alignment, markdown, equation, marp

I've been trying to find a solution to **align multiple equations in [Marp](https://yhatt.github.io/marp/)** (a tool to convert .md files into PDF) but can't find a solution.

I tried using `\begin{equation}......\end{equation}`(which apparently is not supported in Marp), and various combinations of `$....$`, `$$....$$` 
but can't find a hack.

I'm trying to generate something like : 
[image: 1]
but instead I get this:
[image: 2]

here is my code:

```
$$ E_{\theta}[\theta] = \int_{\theta}\theta\ p(\theta)\ d\theta $$
$$ E_D[E_{\theta}[\theta|D]] = \int_D\Bigg\{\int_{\theta}\theta\ p(\theta|D)\ d\theta \Bigg\}\ p(D)\ dD $$
```

What am I missing. There is a solution for R Markdown, but I'm not sure if Marp supports R Markdown. I also can't find a way to import packages in Marp too.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put `$$` at the start and end of the equations - but not after each each equation.
2. Then separate each equation with `\\`.
3. Put an `&` before each equals (where you want it to align)
4. Use the `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}` function.

Here is a simple example:

```
$$\begin{aligned} 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 &= 10 \\
20 \times 80 &= 1600 \end{aligned}$$
```

Here is your example in this format:

```
$$\begin{aligned}E_{\theta}[\theta] &= \int_{\theta}\theta\ p(\theta)\ d\theta \\
E_D[E_{\theta}[\theta|D]] &= \int_D\Bigg\{\int_{\theta}\theta\ p(\theta|D)\ d\theta \Bigg\}\ p(D)\ dD \end{aligned}$$
```

These these examples when rendered:

[math-alignement-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsrFa.png)